# ObjectListView sorting on date

Tags: c#, sorting, date, objectlistview

In my `ObjectListView` I have a column that is a date format, using `{0:d/M HH:mm}` as the date format.  When I click the column header it sorts numerically and not by the date,

e.g.

```
1/2/2013
2/10/2013
3/1/2013
```

Instead of

```
2/10/2013
1/2/2013
3/1/2013
```

How can I set this correctly?

Comment: Not being an expert in ObjectListView, guessing: you need to use .SortListItemsBy(cmpFunc, ascending=None) and use a reformatted date as source (YYYYMMDD)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue. My `ObjectListView` (version 2.6.0) sorts dates correctly.

In fact, despite [what @Victor says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565299/505893), [on the documentation you can read](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/features.html#automatic-sorting):

> ObjectListView will automatically sort the rows when the user clicks on a column header. This sorting understands the data type of the column, so sorting is always correct according to the data type. Sorting does not use the string representation.

Answer (score -1):

By default ObjectListView makes ordering using String data type. Try to use explicit data type for this column in your code, e.g.:

```
olvColumn.DataType = typeof (DateTime);
```

Or add custom sorting like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634041/custom-sorting-with-objectlistview?rq=1)

Comment: This is not true. ObjectListView will sort by the native ordering of the type of data in the column. The programmer doesn't need to do anything to make this happen