# One-time sorting with ObjectListView

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, objectlistview

I have an `ObjectListView` populated with some data. When the user clicks a button, I do some data analysis and I need to sort rows of my `ObjectListView` based on results of my analysis - some rows should be on the top of the view, some rows should follow next...

This sorting is one-time sorting - It is not based on any column of the view and next time the analysis results might be completely different.

Firstly, I tried the most basic situation: I just need to put some rows on the top of the view. I checked this similar question:

[Custom Sorting with ObjectListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13634041/3899583)

and I wrote this piece of code:

```
SortDelegate prevDelegate = myListView.CustomSorter;
IComparer prevComparer = myListView.ListViewItemSorter;
myListView.CustomSorter = delegate(OLVColumn column, SortOrder order)
{
       myListView.ListViewItemSorter = new MyComparer(specialItemsList);
};
myListView.Sort();
myListView.ListViewItemSorter = prevComparer;
myListView.CustomSorter = prevDelegate;
```

where

```
class MyComparer : IComparer
{
    private readonly List<string> specialItemsList;

    public SetPrivilegeComparer(List<string> specialItemsList)
    {
        this.specialItemsList= specialItemsList;
    }

    public int Compare(object xobj, object yobj)
    {
        if (!(xobj is MyListItem && yobj is MyListItem))
            return 0;

        MyListItem x = (MyListItem )xobj;
        MyListItem y = (MyListItem )yobj;

        if (specialItemsList.Contains(x.strVal) && specialItemsList.Contains(y.strVal))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (!specialItemsList.Contains(x.strVal) && !specialItemsList.Contains(y.strVal))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (specialItemsList.Contains(x.strVal) && !specialItemsList.Contains(y.strVal))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (!specialItemsList.Contains(x.strVal) && specialItemsList.Contains(y.strVal))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is nothing happens when I run the above code, the `Compare` method is never called. I studied http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-do-some-fancy-sorting, but I probably did not understand the trick with `CustomSorter` and `ListViewItemSorter` - what are responsibilities of these two classes? Thanks for any idea!

Comment: What about using the `BeforeSorting` event and perform the one time sorting there?

Comment: @Rev1.0 Thank for your comment, I will try it and I will let you know